# Differential equations involving matrices

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been recently doing some differential equations of the form:
$$x=x(t),x\in{\mathbb{R}}^n,M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n},n\in\mathbb{N}^+,t\in\mathbb{R}^+<\infty$$
the simplest of which would be:
$$x'=Mx,\,x(0)=x_0$$
which is easy to solve as the following:
$$x=e^{Mt}x_0$$
my question is about calculating this term $e^{Mt}$ as I would do it as the following:
$$e^z=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{z^i}{i!}\Rightarrow e^{Mt}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{M^it^i}{i!}$$
now to calculate this $M^i$ term the easiest way seems to be to assume that:
$$M=PDP^{-1}$$
so that:
$$M^i=PD^iP^{-1}$$
I believe I can go on to say:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{M^it^i}{i!}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{PD^iP^{-1}t^i}{i!}=P\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{D^it^i}{i!}P^{-1}$$
I think I can split the sum in this way since $t$ is effectively just a magnitude so the position wrt $P,P^{-1}$ is irrelevant. Now since I am looking at $x$ for $t$ over a finite range it seems to me that for the sum above to converge then the following sum must also:
$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{D^i}{i!}$$
since this is a square matrix, the cells contained range from $D_{11}$ to $D_{nn}$ so for any term in the matrix $D_{jk}$ the following must be true for the sum to converge:
$$\left|\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{D_{jk}^i}{i!}\right|<\infty$$
what restrictions are imposed on this (if any) as I feel there are none. And if that is the case, does a solution always exist provided that $M$ can satify $M=PDP^{-1}$? Thanks

Comment: Small adjustment:  $D$ is diagonal, so the only nonzero entries are $D_{jj}$.  In the last display, you only need consider these nonzero entries -- the zeroes give easily convergent sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $D$ is more than a square matrix, it is a diagonal matrix. If the diagonal elements of $D$ are $d_1,...,d_n$ then $D^i$ has diagonal elements $d_1^i,...,d_n^i$.

The sum is always convergent, it's the power series for the exponential function on $\mathbb{R}$:
$$e^x=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^i}{i!}$$
with $x=d_i$ being one of the elements on the diagonal of $D$.

One can show that the exponential series for $A$ is always convergent, regardless of whether $M$ is diagonalizable or not, that is whether you can write $M=PDP^{-1}$ or not. Are you familiar with matrix norms?

Comment: I am not familiar with matrix norms, how do I show a solution exists and go on to calculate it if $M$ is not diagonalizable?

Comment: You can use matrix norms to show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{M^n}{n!}$ always converges to a matrix which we call $e^M$.

To calculate it practically, the problem is to deal with the powers $M^n$. You can use a Jordan decomposition $M=P^{-1}JP$ where $J$ is the Jordan Form of $M$. $J$ is generally not diagonal but can be written as $J=D+N$ where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ is nilpotent. The powers of $D$ are simple, and $N^i=0$ for some integer $i$.

See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: wow thats amazing thank you! This is not my expertese but I would love to get to know this area of maths better